# Program stuck at cv.VideoCapture(0) line when using custom docker image

Tags: python, docker, opencv

First, while I'm waiting for an answer here, I am still looking around in google, but since my situation is pretty specific I doubt that I am going to find a similar post.

Also, I use ubuntu 20.04, python3.8.5 and OpenCV 4.5.1.

NOTE: I'm looking into putting my image on docker hub to make it easier on anyone that might want to reproduce this...  -Unfortunately, trying to send the repo GitHub to Docker Hub return the following error: `buildx call failed with: error: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed` I'm probably going to return on this come Monday (15/02)

Now, please do understand that my framecap.py file, the program which I have a problem with, work perfectly well **outside** my container.
This is framecap.py:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import time
print(cv.__version__)
print("test-2")
# camSet = 'v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! autovideosink'
# camSet = 'videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink'
print("test-1")

camSet = 0
print("test0")

cam = cv.VideoCapture(camSet)
print("test1")

if not cam.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
print("test2")

frame_array = []
print("test3")

counter=0
print("test4")

while counter<=20:
    print(counter, "1")

    ret, frame = cam.read()
    print(counter, "2")

    cv.imshow('myCam', frame)
    print(counter, "3")

    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    height, width, layers = frame.shape
    print(counter, "4")

    size = (width,height)
    print(counter, "5")

    frame_array.append(frame)
    print(counter, "6")

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
    counter+=1
    print(counter, "7")

cam.release()
out = cv.VideoWriter('testvideo.avi' ,cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 30, size)
for i in range(len(frame_array)):
    out.write(frame_array[i])
out.release()

cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now, when executed inside my container, this is the outcome:

```sh
root@blabla-3:/data# python3 framecap.py
4.5.1
test-2
test-1
test0
```

And it stay at `test0` until I `Ctrl + C`

Since this work outside my container, it obviously don't come from my python file. Thus, the following is my command to launch the container:

```sh
$ sudo docker run -dit --name test -v ~/datapython:/data --rm --device /dev/video0 --net=host -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY opencv-gstreamer bash
```

Now, the Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
FROM restreamio/gstreamer:1.18.2.0-prod
WORKDIR /app


RUN apt update && apt install -y python3-pip
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
# Various Python and C/build deps
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
#     gstreamer1.0*
# RUN apt install -y ubuntu-restricted-extras
RUN apt install -y build-essential cmake git pkg-config libgtk-3-dev \
    libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev \
    libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev \
    gfortran openexr libatlas-base-dev python3-dev python3-numpy \
    libtbb2 libtbb-dev libdc1394-22-dev libopenexr-dev \
    libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev



# Install Open CV - Warning, this takes absolutely forever

RUN git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git /home/thomas/Desktop/opencv-gstreamer/opencv && \
    cd /home/thomas/Desktop/opencv-gstreamer/opencv && \
    git checkout 4.5.1 && \
#     unzip 4.5.1.zip && \
#     rm 4.5.1.zip && \
#     mv opencv-3.0.0 OpenCV && \
#     cd OpenCV && \
    mkdir build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)") \
    -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) \
    -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") \
    -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") \
    -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON .. && \
    make -j4 && \
    make install


COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

I would like to know if I missed something in my image build to allow my framecap.py to do his work, or in my container run command, but I haven't found an answer yet...

NOTE:
The webcam that i use has a little blue light if it is On. When executing my python file in the container, this light is **present**, meaning that my webcam is working.

Also, this is requirements.txt :

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Following the suggestions in the comments, i did `xhost +local:docker` and added `-v /dev/video0:/dev/video0` to my docker run. By doing so, the execution of `framecap.py` return this:

```
root@blabla-3:/data# python3 framecap.py
4.5.1
test-2
test-1
test0
[ WARN:0] global /path/to/image/opencv-gstreamer/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1824) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Could not open device '/dev/video0' for reading and writing.
[ WARN:0] global /path/to/image/opencv-gstreamer/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (914) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global /path/to/image/opencv-gstreamer/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (501) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
[ WARN:0] global /path/to/image/opencv-gstreamer/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
test1
Cannot open camera
```

In my python file, commenting out `camSet = 0` and commenting in `camSet = 'v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! autovideosink'`, then executing the file get me this:

```
root@blabla-3:/data# python3 framecap.py
4.5.1
test-2
test-1
test0
[ WARN:0] global /path/to/image/opencv-gstreamer/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (824) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: cannot find appsink in manual pipeline
[ WARN:0] global /path/to/image/opencv-gstreamer/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (501) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
[ERROR:0] global /path/to/image/opencv-gstreamer/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (140) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.1) /path/to/image/opencv-gstreamer/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! autovideosink in function 'icvExtractPattern'


test1
Cannot open camera
```

Comment: Looking at your docker run command, I would recommend you to try this : --device=/dev/video0:/dev/video0.  This maps the Host OS webcam to the container system. Works well for linux systems.

Comment: Hello, i tried `$ sudo docker run -dit --name test -v ~/datapython:/data --rm --device=/dev/video0:/dev/video0 --net=host -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY opencv-gstreamer bash` like you said, but there was no change :/

Comment: I feel there is an issue with exposing the Camera from the linux host to docker system. I would try  to expose your xhost to the container.  ` xhost +local:docker ` , before docker run. Also, would try using it as a volume :  -v /devvideo0 ......  as a replacement to --device.

Comment: i edited my post with the results of your recommendations :)

Comment: Please don’t gratuitously repeat the tags in the question title.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Noted.